How to Modify the MongoDB Document Before Logging in Log4j2 NoSQL MongoDB Appender?
I'm using Log4j2 with the MongoDB NoSQL appender to send logs to a MongoDB database. The appender is working correctly, and the logs are being stored in MongoDB as documents. However, I would like to modify the document before it is saved to the database (e.g., adding, removing, or altering fields).
I've tried using PatternLayout and JsonLayout, but I haven't been able to modify the document as I need. Here's a simplified version of my current log4j2.xml configuration:
<Appenders>
    <NoSql name="mongoDbAppender">
        <MongoDb4 connection="${spring:mongo.connection.string} />
        <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="true">
            <KeyValuePair key="testField" value="testValue" />
        </JsonLayout>
    </NoSql>
</Appenders>

Using this the KeyValuePair does not seem to be added to the document.
Is there a way to intercept or modify the log document before it is sent to MongoDB? I would like to customize the log document beyond what is provided by the layout configurations. Any pointers or suggestions on how to achieve this?
Any help or examples would be appreciated.

Possibly, you can use MongoDB Change Streams to alter the document being inserted/modified into the database. This is purely on the database side programming.

As documented in NoSQL Appender Formatting, there are two ways you can modify the structure of the NoSQL document logged:

You can use a layout that returns a MapMessage. Most of the layouts (including JsonLayout) return a String, so you can not use them.

You can add single fields as nested KeyValuePair elements directly in the <NoSQL> element. The "value" attribute supports runtime property substitution:
<Appenders>
  <NoSql name="mongoDbAppender">
    <MongoDb4 connection="${spring:mongo.connection.string}"/>
    <KeyValuePair key="testField" value="testValue"/>
    <KeyValuePair key="date" value="$${date:yyyy-mm-dd}"/>
  </NoSql>
</Appenders>




Hello Piotr,
Are there any ways to modify the document (edit or remove fields) before it sent over to the mongo database?

For that kind of changes you would need to implement your own Layout<MapMessage> and register it as Log4j Core Plugin. The values of the MapMessage can be arbitrary objects, so you can create any NoSQL document.
